# How to set the current value to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Problem:** I have the following script that checks if the field has been selected. If the dropdown field has not been selected, no results will be displayed():

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var $zip = $('#zip');
    var $city = $('#city');
    var $hospital = $('#hospital');
    var $miles = $('#miles');

    $zip.on("change",function(){
        $('#city option[value=""]').prop('selected',true).trigger('input');
        $hospital.val('').trigger('input');
    });

    $city.on("change",function(){
        $zip.val('').trigger('input');
        $miles.val('').trigger('input');
    });

    $hospital.on("change",function(){
        $zip.val('').trigger('input');
        $miles.val('').trigger('input');
    });
});
function checkTextField() {
    var distance = document.forms["UrgentCareSearch"]["distance"].value;
    var zip = document.forms["UrgentCareSearch"]["zip"].value;
    /*if(zip && distance || !zip && !distance){
        return true;
    }else{
        var alertMessage = "Please Select Distance When You Are Entering A Zip Code.";
        alert(alertMessage);
        return false;
    }*/

    if(zip && !distance){
        var alertMessage = "Please Select Distance When You Are Entering A Zip Code.";
        alert(alertMessage);
        return false; //Does not submit form
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

here is the form:

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
    <form name="UrgentCareSearch" ng-submit="SearchUrgentCare(searchParam);" novalidate role="form">
        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="hospital" ng-model="searchParam.HospitalName" placeholder="Hospital Name" type="text" /></div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option>  
        <option value=""></option>
                      <cfoutput query="HospCityFind">
                      <option value=#officecity#>#officecity#</option>
                    </cfoutput> 
                  </select></div>

        <hr />
        <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important">* or Search by Zip code radius *</div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group"><!---<select class="form-control" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance" ng-options="mile.value for mile in miles"></select>--->
                    <select class="form-control" id="miles" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance" required convert-to-number>

                        <option value={{v.value}} ng-repeat="(k , v) in miles track by $index">{{v.value}}</option>
                    </select>
                        <div class="input-group-addon">miles</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding widthZip">
                <div class="form-group"><input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group"><input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" onclick="return checkTextField();" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search" /></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

So when the form is first generated, I enter a zip code and select the submit button. When I do that, in the beginning, instead of showing the alert notifying the user to select a mileage, it will display the result based on the default set to 5.

I would like to set the value to 0/empty if the user has selected the option to look up urgent care by zip code, only in the beginning (meaning when the form is first generated), otherwise, set it to default 5 miles when user looks up by entering a name of a urgent care and city.

Comment: Hi @Roberto. Toss a quick jsfiddle in here and we can really dig around and fully get what you're trying to do =).

Comment: @DanielD Hello here is the jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=TCM6Dhs2GF Also I am new to javascript and angular so my apologies if my code is not understandable

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/robontrix/s0tanpqh/#&togetherjs=TCM6Dhs2GF

Comment: @DanielD: I have updated my question.

Comment: @DanielD I have a question: how would I add the ng-model="SearchParam.Distance" into my checktextField?

Comment: Real quick... I notice you have your controller in there, but you aren't using it populate your select list. Are you going to want to use the angular miles array?

Comment: @DanielD: Let me post the whole thing code so it makes since why miles is there

Comment: @DanielD Posted the code

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to remove all of the "UPDATE"s and have a single question? Right now it's very confusing determining which question you want answered...

Comment: @DanielD Is there a way in the form at the beginning, when the zip code is selected, miles is blank and the alert will appear?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan You got it

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Question have been edited

Comment: @Roberto Honestly I would restructure this project a bit. I would handle all that functionality inside of your controllers on the angular side. Right now I feel that you're making it more complicated trying to use both jquery and angular like that. Then inside your controller, you can detect changes using `$watch` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#methods_$watch). You can also move your functions into the controller as well.

Comment: @DanielD I am new to this and based on how the site is design (not design by me), it has both and do to my knowledge, I am not able to do that (plus the lead doesn't want to change it :( ). Thank You for your suggestion

Comment: @DanielD Based on what I am understanding from $watch, it will monitor the value and change it. My question is, how would I do this only at the beginning? Meaning, when the form is first appears, if the user enters zip, display alert. Otherwise, dont?

Comment: Ok bummer on the restructuring. If I understand this right, you can just use jQuery to trigger once someone types in their zip. Here's a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/dCFd2/802/. Did you mean something like that?

Comment: @DanielD yes, you have no idea how much sadness it brings me.... The fiddle you sent is kinda what I am talking about. Let me be a little more clear. So at the beginning of the form, meaning when the user first enters the page that contains the form, if the user enters a zip, the alert will only appear when the user has submit the form. So, it would be like the checkTextField that I created above.

Comment: @DanielD The problem I am having is the value of the field is not blank, it is set by default 5 miles. I would like to set the value of the miles blank, only at the beginning when the form is first generated, if zip is selected. If it is selected, the alert will fire after the user has submit the form. Otherwise, leave the value default to 5. I have tried the following but it appears not to work: $zip.one("change", function(){$miles.val('').trigger('input');});